# How to get distinct values and sum the total on JSON using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, arraylist

How do you get the data from distinct values also sum the total values from the same unique row

Here is the JSON Data result

[image]

As you can see they have the same full name. How do you get the distinct value while sum the total `priceGross`.

The result should be returning
eg. `"Khalem Williams"` and adding the total `priceGross` `" 1200 + 1200 " = 2400`

result return

```
FullName : "Khalem Williams" 
TotalPriceGross: "2400"
```

I'm getting the distinct values with the code below but I'm wondering how to sum the total priceGross while also getting the distinct values.

```
var countTotal = [];

$.each(data.aaData.data,function(index, value){
          if ($.inArray(value.invoiceToFullName, countTotal)==-1) {
                    countTotal.push(value.invoiceToFullName);
          }
});
```

Comment: Can you confirm this is what you're asking, please: the value at `data.aaData.data` is an array of invoice objects, each of which contains, among others, properties `invoiceToFullName` and `priceGross` (you highlight `priceNett` but specified `priceGross`), and you'd like to pivot that into an object containing names and the sum of price?

Comment: `{"Khalem Williams":2400, ...}` output would be better and let Object merge the unique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would honestly suggest converting your data to an object with names as keys (unique) and total gross prices as values:

```
{
  "Khalem Williams": 2400,
  "John Doe": 2100
}
```

However, I have included in the snippet below example code for how to convert your data to an array of objects as well. I used a combination of `Object.keys`, `Array#reduce` and `Array#map`.

```js
var data = {
  aaData: {
    data: [{
        invoiceToFullName: "Khalem Williams",
        priceGross: 1200
      },
      {
        invoiceToFullName: "Khalem Williams",
        priceGross: 1200
      },
      {
        invoiceToFullName: "John Doe",
        priceGross: 500
      },
      {
        invoiceToFullName: "John Doe",
        priceGross: 1600
      },
    ]
  }
}

var map = data.aaData.data.reduce(function(map, invoice) {
  var name = invoice.invoiceToFullName
  var price = +invoice.priceGross
  map[name] = (map[name] || 0) + price
  return map
}, {})

console.log(map)

var array = Object.keys(map).map(function(name) {
  return {
    fullName: name,
    totalPriceGross: map[name]
  }
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: This helps a lot. I didn't know about the predefined "reduce" function from javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just created my own dummy data resembling yours hope you get the idea, if not you can paste your json and i can adjust my solution, was just lazy to recreate your json.

Your problem seems to be a typical group by field from sql.

Sample data:

```
   var resultsData = [{name: 'sipho', amount: 10}, {name: 'themba', amount: 30}, {name: 'sipho', amount: 60}, {name: 'naidoo', amount: 30}, {name: 'gupta', amount: 70}, {name: 'naidoo', amount: 10}];
```

Get value of customer(field) you going to group by:

```
var customers = $.unique(resultsData.map(function(value){return value.name}));
```

Go through each customer and add to their sum:

```
var desiredSummary = customers.map(function(customer){
    var sum =0; 
    $.each(test,function(index, value){sum+=(value.name==customer?value.amount:0)}); 
    return {customer: customer, sum: sum}
});
```

Hope it helps, Happy coding