# creating top 5 aggregation with ramdajs

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to transform this input

```
[
        { country: 'France', value: 100 },
        { country: 'France', value: 100 },
        { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
        { country: 'England', value: 400 },
        { country: 'England', value: 400 },
        { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
        { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
        { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
]
```

into the output

```
[
      { country: 'England', value: 800 },
      { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
      { country: 'France', value: 200 },
      { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
      { country: 'Other', value: 8 }
]
```

Which is basically doing a ***sum of values for the top 4 + others countries***.

I am using javascript with [ramdajs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/), and I only managed to do it in a  [somehow cumbersome way so far](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20sumValue%20%3D%20%28acc%2C%20cur%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20country%3A%20prop%28%27country%27%2C%20cur%29%2C%0A%20%20value%3A%20propOr%280%2C%20%27value%27%2C%20cur%29%20%2B%20propOr%280%2C%20%27value%27%2C%20acc%29%0A%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20groupOthersKeeping%20%3D%20contriesToKeep%20%3D%3E%20reduce%28%28acc%2C%20curr%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20%28acc.length%20%3C%20contriesToKeep%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20append%28curr%2C%20acc%29%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20top%20%3D%20take%28contriesToKeep%29%28acc%29%0A%20%20%20%20const%20others%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20country%3A%20%27Others%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20propOr%280%2C%27value%27%2C%20curr%29%20%2B%20propOr%280%2C%20%27value%27%2C%20acc%5BcontriesToKeep%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20append%28others%2C%20top%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%2C%20%5B%5D%29%0A%0Aconst%20f%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20reduceBy%28sumValue%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20prop%28%27country%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20values%2C%0A%20%20sortBy%28prop%28%27value%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20reverse%2C%0A%20%20groupOthersKeeping%284%29%0A%29%0A%0Af%28%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27France%27%2C%20value%3A%20100%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27France%27%2C%20value%3A%20100%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Romania%27%2C%20value%3A%20500%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27England%27%2C%20value%3A%20400%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27England%27%2C%20value%3A%20400%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Spain%27%2C%20value%3A%20130%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Albania%27%2C%20value%3A%204%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Hungary%27%2C%20value%3A%203%20%7D%0A%5D%29).

I am looking for an elegant solution: any Functional Programmer out there able to provide their solution? Or any idea of ramda methods that would help?

Comment: please add your code, even if it's a very cumbersome way

Comment: and does the answer required to use that library's function only?

Comment: I just edited the question to add a link to a runable version of my solution. 
Regarding the library, I'm looking for the most functional approach to resolve this issue, and I can't introduce any other functional library such as Iodash just for this algorithm but native javascript is ok.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590750/how-to-get-distinct-values-and-sum-the-total-on-json-using-js

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge: I would suggest that this is not a duplicate of that.  Yes, you probably want the grouping behavior, but there is much more involved here, including an additional sort, splitting into top-4 and others groups, then combining the others.  This is a significantly more complex requirement.

Comment: I love the variety of solutions this question has generated!

Comment: @ScottSauyet To be honest me too...but I don't know how which one to accept now... I hope votes will help me to decide on one :-)

Comment: Please don't use the votes for that.  Choose the one that best suits you, in whatever manner.  Mine is one of the most concise.  appleapple's has a longer pipeline but the simplest steps.  customcommander has by far the most detailed exposition.  Choose the best answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give it a try and try to use it's function for most things. and keep it single `pipe`

```
const f = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('country')),
  map(map(prop('value'))),
  map(sum),
  toPairs(),
  sortBy(prop(1)),
  reverse(),
  addIndex(map)((val, idx) => idx<4?val:['Others',val[1]]),
  groupBy(prop(0)),
  map(map(prop(1))),
  map(sum),
  toPairs(),
  map(([a,b])=>({'country':a,'value':b}))
)
```

[Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20f%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%28prop%28%27country%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28map%28prop%28%27value%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28sum%29%2C%0A%20%20toPairs%28%29%2C%0A%20%20sortBy%28prop%281%29%29%2C%0A%20%20reverse%28%29%2C%0A%20%20addIndex%28map%29%28%28val%2C%20idx%29%20%3D%3E%20idx%3C4%3Fval%3A%5B%27Others%27%2Cval%5B1%5D%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20groupBy%28prop%280%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28map%28prop%281%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28sum%29%2C%0A%20%20toPairs%28%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28%28%5Ba%2Cb%5D%29%3D%3E%28%7B%27country%27%3Aa%2C%27value%27%3Ab%7D%29%29%2C%0A%29%0A%0Af%28%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27France%27%2C%20value%3A%20100%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27France%27%2C%20value%3A%20100%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Romania%27%2C%20value%3A%20500%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27England%27%2C%20value%3A%20400%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27England%27%2C%20value%3A%20400%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Spain%27%2C%20value%3A%20130%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Albania%27%2C%20value%3A%204%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Hungary%27%2C%20value%3A%203%20%7D%0A%5D%29)

---

However, I don't think it's any way readable.

Answer (score 5):

*(Each step gets the output of the previous step. Everything will be put together in the end.)*

**Step 1: Get a map of sums**

You can transform this:

```
[
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
  { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
  { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
]
```

into this:

```
{
  Albania: 4,
  England: 800,
  France: 200,
  Hungary: 3,
  Romania: 500,
  Spain: 130
}
```

With this:

```
const reducer = reduceBy((sum, {value}) => sum + value, 0);
const reduceCountries = reducer(prop('country'));
```

**Step 2: Convert that back into a sorted array**

```
[
  { country: "Hungary", value: 3 },
  { country: "Albania", value: 4 },
  { country: "Spain", value: 130 },
  { country: "France", value: 200 },
  { country: "Romania", value: 500 },
  { country: "England", value: 800 }
]
```

You can do this with:

```
const countryFromPair = ([country, value]) => ({country, value});
pipe(toPairs, map(countryFromPair), sortBy(prop('value')));
```

**Step 3: Create two sub groups, the non-top-4 countries and the top-4 countries**

```
[
  [
    { country: "Hungary", value: 3},
    { country: "Albania", value: 4}
  ],
  [
    { country: "Spain", value: 130 },
    { country: "France", value: 200 },
    { country: "Romania", value: 500 },
    { country: "England", value: 800 }
  ]
]
```

Which you can do with this:

```
splitAt(-4)
```

**Step 4: Merge the first sub group**

```
[
  [
    { country: "Others", value: 7 }
  ],
  [
    { country: "Spain", value: 130 },
    { country: "France", value: 200 },
    { country: "Romania", value: 500 },
    { country: "England", value: 800 }
  ]
]
```

With this:

```
over(lensIndex(0), compose(map(countryFromPair), toPairs, reduceOthers));
```

**Step 5: Flatten the entire array**

```
[
  { country: "Others", value: 7 },
  { country: "Spain", value: 130 },
  { country: "France", value: 200 },
  { country: "Romania", value: 500 },
  { country: "England", value: 800 }
]
```

With

```
flatten
```

---

*Complete working example*

```
const data = [
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
  { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
  { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
];

const reducer = reduceBy((sum, {value}) => sum + value, 0);
const reduceOthers = reducer(always('Others'));
const reduceCountries = reducer(prop('country'));
const countryFromPair = ([country, value]) => ({country, value});

const top5 = pipe(
  reduceCountries,
  toPairs,
  map(countryFromPair),
  sortBy(prop('value')),
  splitAt(-4),
  over(lensIndex(0), compose(map(countryFromPair), toPairs, reduceOthers)),
  flatten
);

top5(data)
```

Comment: `reduceBy`:  I knew I was missing something!  Very nice technique, and an excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks @ScottSauyet. Looking at your answer using `zipObj` to reconstruct an object from a pair feels more natural than what I'm doing. Although I'm not fully grokking `lift` yet, it also feels more idiomatic in this case. I'll consider this too.

Comment: This [discussion of `lift`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36558598/1243641) may help.  It converts a function operating of values to one operating on *containers* of those values.  While this could be something like `Maybe`, it can also be a function returning that value.  That's what I use here.  With functions, `lift(f)(g, h)` is something like `(...args) => f(g(...args), h(...args))`.  This is much like `converge`, but with a more standard (and slightly less flexible) behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach:

```js
const combineAllBut = (n) => pipe(drop(n), pluck(1), sum, of, prepend('Others'), of)

const transform = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('country')),
  map(pluck('value')),
  map(sum),
  toPairs,
  sort(descend(nth(1))),
  lift(concat)(take(4), combineAllBut(4)),
  map(zipObj(['country', 'value']))
)

const countries = [{ country: 'France', value: 100 }, { country: 'France', value: 100 }, { country: 'Romania', value: 500 }, { country: 'England', value: 400 }, { country: 'England', value: 400 }, { country: 'Spain', value: 130 }, { country: 'Albania', value: 4 }, { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }]

console.log(transform(countries))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<script>
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, sum, of, prepend, toPairs, sort, descend, nth, lift, concat, take, drop, zipObj} = ramda
</script>
```

Except for the one complex line (`lift(concat)(take(4), combineAllBut(4))`) and the associated helper function (`combineAllBut`), this is a set of simple transformations.  That helper function is probably not useful outside this function, so it would be perfectly acceptable to inline it as `lift(concat)(take(4), pipe(drop(4), pluck(1), sum, of, prepend('Others'), of))`, but I find the resulting function a little too difficult to read.

Note that that function will return something like `[['Other', 7]]`, which is a format meaningless outside the fact that we're going to then `concat` it with an array of the top four.  So there's at least some argument for removing the final `of` and replacing `concat` with `flip(append)`.  I didn't do so since that helper function means nothing except in context of this pipeline.  But I would understand if someone would choose otherwise.

I like the rest of this function, and it seems to be a good fit for the Ramda pipeline style.  But that helper function spoils it to some degree.  I would love to hear suggestions for simplifying it.

### Update

Then answer from customcommander demonstrated a simplification I could take, by using `reduceBy` instead of of the `groupBy -> map(pluck) -> map(sum)` dance in the above approach.  That makes for a definite improvement.

```js
const combineAllBut = (n) => pipe(drop(n), pluck(1), sum, of, prepend('Others'), of)

const transform = pipe(
  reduceBy((a, {value}) => a + value, 0, prop('country')),
  toPairs,
  sort(descend(nth(1))),
  lift(concat)(take(4), combineAllBut(4)),
  map(zipObj(['country', 'value']))
)

const countries = [{ country: 'France', value: 100 }, { country: 'France', value: 100 }, { country: 'Romania', value: 500 }, { country: 'England', value: 400 }, { country: 'England', value: 400 }, { country: 'Spain', value: 130 }, { country: 'Albania', value: 4 }, { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }]

console.log(transform(countries))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script>
<script>
const {pipe, reduceBy, prop, map, pluck, sum, of, prepend, toPairs, sort, descend, nth, lift, concat, take, drop, zipObj} = ramda
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can slightly simplify `groupOthersKeeping` by splitting the array before reducing it, in terms of ramda, that may look like as follows:

```
const groupOthersKeeping = contriesToKeep => arr => [
    ...slice(0, contriesToKeep, arr),
    reduce(
      (acc, i) => ({ ...acc, value: acc.value + i.value }),
      { country: 'Others', value: 0 },
      slice(contriesToKeep, Infinity, arr)
    )
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using more ramda function but not sure that is better:

```
let country = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('country')),
  map(pluck('value')),
  map(sum)
)([
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
  { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
  { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
]);

let splitCountry = pipe(
  map((k) => ({country: k, value: country[k]})),
  sortBy(prop('value')),
  reverse,
  splitAt(4)
)(keys(country));

splitCountry[0].push({country: 'Others', value: sum(map(prop('value'))(splitCountry[1]))});
splitCountry[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents.

```
const a = [
    { country: 'France', value: 100 },
    { country: 'France', value: 100 },
    { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
    { country: 'England', value: 400 },
    { country: 'England', value: 400 },
    { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
    { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
    { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
];

const diff = (a, b) => b.value - a.value;
const addValues = (acc, {value}) => R.add(acc,value);
const count = R.reduce(addValues, 0);
const toCountry = ({country}) => country;
const toCountryObj = (x) => ({'country': x[0], 'value': x[1] });
const reduceC = R.reduceBy(addValues, [], toCountry);

const [countries, others] = R.compose(
    R.splitAt(4), 
    R.sort(diff), 
    R.chain(toCountryObj), 
    R.toPairs, 
    reduceC)(a);

const othersArray = [{ 'country': 'Others', 'value': count(others) }];

R.concat(countries, othersArray);
```

[Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20a%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27France%27%2C%20value%3A%20100%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27France%27%2C%20value%3A%20100%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Romania%27%2C%20value%3A%20500%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27England%27%2C%20value%3A%20400%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27England%27%2C%20value%3A%20400%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Spain%27%2C%20value%3A%20130%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Albania%27%2C%20value%3A%204%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20country%3A%20%27Hungary%27%2C%20value%3A%203%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20diff%20%3D%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20b.value%20-%20a.value%3B%0Aconst%20addValues%20%3D%20%28acc%2C%20%7Bvalue%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20R.add%28acc%2Cvalue%29%3B%0Aconst%20count%20%3D%20R.reduce%28addValues%2C%200%29%3B%0Aconst%20toCountry%20%3D%20%28%7Bcountry%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20country%3B%0Aconst%20toCountryObj%20%3D%20%28x%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%27country%27%3A%20x%5B0%5D%2C%20%27value%27%3A%20x%5B1%5D%20%7D%29%3B%0Aconst%20reduceC%20%3D%20R.reduceBy%28addValues%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20toCountry%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20%5Bcountries%2C%20others%5D%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.splitAt%284%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.sort%28diff%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.chain%28toCountryObj%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.toPairs%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20reduceC%29%28a%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20othersArray%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20%27country%27%3A%20%27Others%27%2C%20%27value%27%3A%20count%28others%29%20%7D%5D%3B%0A%0AR.concat%28countries%2C%20othersArray%29%3B)

Comment: each of the helper functions contain a specialization that makes them difficult to reuse and ends up feeling unnatural in a functional program

Answer (score 1):

I would group by the country, merge each country group to a single object, while summing the value, sort, split to two arrays [highest 4] and [others], merge others to a single object, and concat with the highest 4.

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, values, map, converge, merge, head, pluck, sum, objOf, sort, descend, splitAt, concat, last, of, assoc } = R

const sumProp = key => pipe(pluck(key), sum, objOf(key))

const combineProp = key => converge(merge, [head, sumProp(key)])

const getTop5 = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('country')),
  values, // convert to array of country arrays
  map(combineProp('value')), // merge each sub array to a single object
  sort(descend(prop('value'))), // sort descebdubg by the value property
  splitAt(4), // split to two arrays [4 highest][the rest]
  converge(concat, [ // combine the highest and the others object
    head,
    // combine the rest to the others object wrapped in an array
    pipe(last, combineProp('value'), assoc('country', 'others'), of)
  ])
)

const countries = [{ country: 'France', value: 100 }, { country: 'France', value: 100 }, { country: 'Romania', value: 500 }, { country: 'England', value: 400 }, { country: 'England', value: 400 }, { country: 'Spain', value: 130 }, { country: 'Albania', value: 4 }, { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }]

const result = getTop5(countries)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```js
const aggregate = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop('country')),
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(
    R.applySpec({ 
      country: R.head, 
      value: R.pipe(R.last, R.pluck('value'), R.sum),
    }),
  ),
  R.sort(R.descend(R.prop('value'))),
  R.splitAt(4),
  R.over(
    R.lensIndex(1), 
    R.applySpec({ 
      country: R.always('Others'), 
      value: R.pipe(R.pluck('value'), R.sum),
    }),
  ),
  R.unnest,
);

const data = [
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
  { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
  { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
];

console.log('result', aggregate(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here's two solutions

I think the second is easier to understand even though it's longer

The function "mergeAllWithKeyBy" combines the functionality of "R.mergeAll", "R.mergeWithKey", and "R.groupBy".

```js
const mergeAllWithKeyBy = R.curry((mergeFn, keyFn, objs) =>
  R.values(R.reduceBy(R.mergeWithKey(mergeFn), {}, keyFn, objs)))

const addValue = (k, l, r) => 
  k === 'value' ? l + r : r

const getTop = 
  R.pipe(
    mergeAllWithKeyBy(addValue, R.prop('country')),
    R.sort(R.descend(R.prop('value'))),
    R.splitAt(4),
    R.adjust(-1, R.map(R.assoc('country', 'Others'))),
    R.unnest,
    mergeAllWithKeyBy(addValue, R.prop('country')),
  )
  
const data = [
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
  { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
  { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
]

console.log(getTop(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const getTop = (data) => {
  const getCountryValue =
    R.prop(R.__, R.reduceBy((y, x) => y + x.value, 0, R.prop('country'), data))
    
  const countries = 
    R.uniq(R.pluck('country', data))
  
  const [topCounties, bottomCountries] = 
    R.splitAt(4, R.sort(R.descend(getCountryValue), countries))
  
  const others = {
    country: 'Others', 
    value: R.sum(R.map(getCountryValue, bottomCountries))
  }
  
  const top =
    R.map(R.applySpec({country: R.identity, value: getCountryValue}), topCounties)
  
  return R.append(others, top)
}

const data = [
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'France', value: 100 },
  { country: 'Romania', value: 500 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'England', value: 400 },
  { country: 'Spain', value: 130 },
  { country: 'Albania', value: 4 },
  { country: 'Hungary', value: 3 }
]

console.log(getTop(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```